# Does dojo/_base/fx support promises?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am need to execute a method after an animation on a dom element ends.
At the moment I am using the following code with no success.

I would like to know if dojo, support promise for animation, if no, I would like to know in which way I could work it out.

```
       fx.fadeOut({ node: 'target'}).play().then(function () {
            // do smt here
        }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes can you use the registered Callback of the `FadeOut` function.

the `fadeOut` (`dojo/_base/fx` function which returns an annimation instance)
provides 5 registred callback functions :

- beforeBegin
- onBegin
- onEnd
- onPlay
- onAnimate (with argument)

In your case you need to make some actions when the animation is done so passe the `onEnd` function in the `FadOut` arguments,  it should look like :

```
fx.fadeOut({
    node:"target",
    onEnd: function(){
         // Some stuff at the end of the animation.
    }
}).play();
```

you can also use the above callback as args .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using `'dojo/on'` and subscribing to the `End` event on `fx.fadeOut()`. Still I am very interesting to understand if there are better way for the same result.

```
       var anim = fx.fadeOut({ node: 'target'}).play();
        on(anim, "End", function () {
            // dom smt here
        }.bind(this));
```